# Creating and Implementing Interfaces Codeigniter

Tags: interface, codeigniter-3

I am using codeigniter 3. I was wondering if there is a way to create and implement interfaces in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if you can make the CodeIgniter framework follow your Interfaces, you could, but it would require a whole lot of refactoring in their framework, and probably wouldn't be worth the work.

If you're asking if you can add Interfaces for your custom classes while using CodeIgniter, of course you can.

```
interface modular{
...
}
```